# iOS ivar alloc/init assigns memory address to another ivar

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I've declared two NSMutableArrays in the interface of one of my view controllers, as you can see in the code below. However, after synthesizing the properties, I attempt to initialize my class' ivars in viewDidLoad. If I step over this process in debugger, I see that it is offsetting memory allocation by one ivar, if that makes any sense. So, for example, as I am initializing the first NSMutableArray, I can watch the memory address get assigned to the other NSMutableArray ivar.  The NSMutableArray that the code should be initializing remains a null memory address. This odd "offset" in memory allocations is try for initializing the second NSMutableArray too...it is initialized in my DataHelper ivar's memory location.  This is causing errors to be thrown later in the code like:

```
-[DataHelper count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Where it is expecting a reference to an NSMutableArray in memory, it is instead pointing to the DataHelper memory address.  Has anyone ever experienced anything like this?  I'm using ARC, the latest version of Xcode, and iOS 5.1.

#### MyViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DataHelper.h"

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController
{
    DataHelper *dataHelper;
    NSMutableArray *recentPosts;
    NSMutableArray *popularPosts;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) DataHelper *dataHelper;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *recentPosts;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *popularPosts;

@end
```

#### viewDidLoad in MyViewController.m

```
@implementation MyViewController

@synthesize dataHelper, recentPosts, popularPosts;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    recentPosts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    popularPosts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    dataHelper = [[DataHelper alloc] init];

    // I've also tried initializing the ivars as above, with "self." prefix

    recentPosts = [dataHelper getSuggestionsByMostRecent:1];
    popularPosts = [dataHelper getSuggestionsByPopular:1];
}
```

Comment: Can you show us where you synthesize the properties and where you set the properties to actual values please?

Comment: `DataHelper` is the class name, did you mean `[dataHelper count]` (lowercase d), or is that a typo in your question?

Comment: @JoshuaHensley - and where do you get the unrecognised selector error?

Comment: [DataHelper count] is the error the debugger is throwing. It is printing the class name out. The problem is that my second NSMutableArray ivar is being inited to the dataHelper ivar's memory location.  My code is calling [popularPosts count]...but it sees the dataHelper ivar...hence the unrecognized selector error.

Comment: Why are you initializing recentPosts and popularPosts when you overwrite the value immediately??..

Comment: @MartinUllrich You're right - I should not be doing it like that. The problem still persists when I change it, though. So, if all I did in viewDidLoad was recentPosts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; popularPosts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  The memory is still being assigned to wrong ivar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are memory readout issues with LLDB in XCode (4.3.1 seems to be affected too) so i suggest you use GDB for debugging.

Comment: Thanks so much Martin!  Turns out that it is some kind of LLDB bug. I switched my scheme over to GDB and all is golden!

Answer (score 1):

ARC expects your method names to follow the [cocoa(-touch) naming conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/Articles/NamingMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001282-BCIGIJJF). 
and `getSuggestionsByMostRecent` violates that convention. Especially this one:

> Use “get” only for methods that return objects and values indirectly. You should use this form for methods only when multiple items need to be returned.

that would be a valid get-method (not a good one though): `- (void)getString:(NSString **)str`

Without using correct naming scheme ARC does not know where to add retain or releases.

Try to rename your method to something like `suggestionsSortedByMostRecent:`. Without the get.

Comment: Hi Matthias.  If you see my comment on my original post, this ivar memory allocation issue persists, even when I make no method calls like [dataHelper getSuggestionsByMostRecent];  and simply alloc/init the NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 0):

I would synthesize like this:

```
@synthesize dataHelper = _dataHelper;
// same for the other two here
```

and use _dataHelper only.

And for adding the posts, didn't you want to do this instead:

```
[_recentPosts addObjectsFromArray:[_dataHelper getSuggestionsByMostRecent:1]];
```

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely right about the addObjectsFromArray part. As far as your synthesize suggestion goes though, making the distinction between properties/ivar declaration (using underscore) is simply a popular convention. It doesn't change how my ivars memory is being allocated. Still no luck.

Comment: One other thing I'd do is to move `#import "DataHelper.h"` to the .m file replace it by `@class DataHelper;` in the .h file. How is your code looking now? Can you update your post?

Comment: Hi ott, my code really hasn't changed much.  Switching to the GDB debugging fixed the problem. I'm actually eliminating my DataHelper object completely, so my code's pretty basic.  Thanks for your help!